# Как ускорить выполнение команды exec (Docker)

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, exec, dockerfile

Я создаю контейнер:

```
docker run -it -d --env TIMEFORMAT=%3R --name python_container -v (текущая директория)\temp:/temp docker_python_runner bash
```

Через команду `exec` запускаю скрипт внутри контейнера:

```
docker exec -i python_container bash -c "time python temp/temp_file.py" 2>&1
```

Допустим, это будет скрипт, который просто складывает 2 числа (например, *stdin*: 5 10).

**Вывод**:

```
15
0.025
```

Т.е результат работы программы: 15, время выполнения скрипта: 0.025.

**НО!** Измерив общее время выполнения команды `exec`, я получил цифру *1.0805566310882568*

Как увеличить скорость выполнения команды `exec`

Comment: У самого `docker exec` есть накладные расходы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894654/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-docker-exec/64895568 . У меня на одной системе с mac os получается чуть меньше 150ms, на другой -  20ms. Почему у вас (судя по всему на windows) 1 секунда не понятно. Я бы попробовал выполнить команду  команду `docker exec` с виртуальной машины линукс, где запущен докер, чтоб посмотреть насколько большой вклад вносит виртуализация. Так же попробывал бы запустить `time python ...` из докер контейнера напрямую, чтоб исключить все что связано собственно с `docker exec`.